# OpenCL only accepts square images

Tags: opencl, square

I build a funcional openCL program that works totally fine with square images but with a 800x600 or 150x200 I always get noise.

heres is a link for the image: http://s21.postimg.org/od6orka1z/aaaaa.png

Anyone can help me to remove this error in non square images?

Thank you

Comment: Edit your question to show your code.

Comment: I suppose you have two workgroups, they should be 800 and 600. Possibly they are 600 and 600 instead?

Comment: code added, if you need more code like kernel I can add too.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, kernel code would be useful.

Comment: kernel added, the gaussian thing is because I adapt the code from a gaussian filter example to find some colors and replace them.

Comment: `global_size[0] = height; global_size[1] = width;` are you sure you have these the right way round?

Comment: yes..
What may be the causes?